# Nested Async await inside timer - not returning the desired value

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, mocha.js, chai

I have to test response of endpoints using  Mocha and chai tests. Below is the code for the same :

```
async function getData (userId) {
        let response;
        let interval = setInterval(async () => {
            response = await superagent.get("localhost:3000/user/details/").query({'user': userId}).type('application/json');
            if (response.body["status"] == 'DONE') {
                clearInterval(interval);
                response = await superagent.get("localhost:3000/user/details/get").type('application/json');
            }
        }, 10000);

    return response;    

}
```

Test Code :

```
it('User Get Data', async function () {
        return getData(userId,).then(function (res) {
            expect(res).to.exist;
            expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
            expect(res.body).to.contain('operation');
            expect(res.body["userDetails"]).to.exist;


        });
```

I always get the response as null and my test fails . Kindly let me know where am I going wrong with this code.

Comment: Run mocha with the --delay flag and use setTimeout instead setInterval

Comment: What is it you're trying to do exactly? You want your test to wait for 10s before executing the two `get`-requests?

Comment: I want to call the first api, with the delay of every 10 seconds , till I get the desired status and then call th second api to get final response which can be returned.

Comment: @RajeevAkotkar: Added an answer, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

*Edited to get rid of the while loop:*

You can rewrite `getData` with `async/await` and wrapping your `interval` in a promise. Once the first response is ok, clear the interval, resolve the promise and execute the second call.

In your unit-test simply await this function and then verify the response details. Note that you might want to increase the default mocha-timeout for the test, as this could potentially take a while. Something like:

```
async function getData(userId) {

    const firstResponsePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
            const interval = setInterval(async() => {
                    const response = await superagent.get('localhost:3000/user/details/').query({
                            'user': userId
                        }).type('application/json');
                    if (response.body['status'] == 'DONE') {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        resolve();
                    }

                }, 10000)
        });

    await firstResponsePromise;
    return superagent.get('localhost:3000/user/details/get').type('application/json');

}

// unit test

it('User Get Data', async function () {
    const res = await getData(userId);
    expect(res).to.exist;
    expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
    expect(res.body).to.contain('operation');
    expect(res.body["userDetails"]).to.exist;

});
```

Comment: just to keep the code clean I want to avoid loop and writing new Promise () instead just want to achieve this through  async- await and setInterval. setInterval already does for loop's job here. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @RajeevAkotkar: Updated, please check again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `setInterval` with promises, and never pass an `async function` as a callback when the returned promise is ignored. In your case, use a loop instead:

```
async function getData (userId) {
    let response;
    do {
        await delay(10000);
        response = await superagent.get("localhost:3000/user/details/").query({'user': userId}).type('application/json');
    } while(response.body["status"] != 'DONE');

    return superagent.get("localhost:3000/user/details/get").type('application/json');
}
```

with

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}
```

Comment: That was also my first solution. However OP did not want a loop, so I edited my answer. Could you please elaborate why doing it like this is bad?

Comment: @eol It's unclear *why* the OP would not want a loop, it's the proper solution when using `async`/`await`. `setInterval` is bad because you cannot promisify it, and doing work inside the `setInterval` callback is bad because errors are not handled (the code in your answer has that problem, for example).

Comment: I see, thanks for the feedback. Always learning something new.